# Override the newsletter subscription success email template in Magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, email-templates, newsletter

How can I override the core email template of newsletter subscription success email template in Magento2?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from the admin area

```
Store->Config->Customers->Newsletter-> Subscription Options
```

You can choose what template you want currently it uses

```
vendor\magento\module-newsletter\view\frontend\email\subscr_success.html
```

which is the default one.

Comment: Thank you very much! The path to the template and the template name are what I was looking for.

Comment: no worries glad I could help :)